# How can I show a ProgressBar only after a minimum delay?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I have an `AsyncTask` with an indeterminate `ProgressBar` that typically executes very quickly, but occasionally slowly.  It's undesirable and distracting to for the the progress bar to flash quickly when there is no discernible wait.

Is there a way to delay display of the progress bar without creating another nested `AsyncTask`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Code Droid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11588979/403455), I was able to write an abstract `AsyncTask` class that shows an indeterminate progress bar after a specified delay.  Just extend this class instead of `AsyncTask` and be sure to call `super()` when appropriate:

```
public abstract class AsyncTaskWithDelayedIndeterminateProgress
      <Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {
   private static final int MIN_DELAY = 250;
   private final ProgressDialog progressDialog;
   private final CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

   protected AsyncTaskWithDelayedIndeterminateProgress(Activity activity) {
      progressDialog = createProgressDialog(activity);
      countDownTimer = createCountDownTimer();
   }

   @Override protected void onPreExecute() {
      countDownTimer.start();
   }

   @Override protected void onPostExecute(Result children) {
      countDownTimer.cancel();
      if(progressDialog.isShowing())
         progressDialog.dismiss();
   }

   private ProgressDialog createProgressDialog(Activity activity) {
      final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
      progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
      return progressDialog;
   }

   private CountDownTimer createCountDownTimer() {
      return new CountDownTimer(MIN_DELAY, MIN_DELAY + 1) {
         @Override public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { }

         @Override public void onFinish() {
            progressDialog.show();
         }
      };
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is and it's called a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) and its highly underused.  You can take action at each tick of the timer or when the timer runs out.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are calling onProgressUpdate at least a few times before your AsyncTask is finished.  If that is the case, what you could do is this.  Each time before you call onProgressUpdate, call Thread.sleep(250).  This way your background Thread will pause before communicating with the UI Thread and give the appearance of a longer running task.  Failing that, I'd probably need to see your code or get some more info.

Comment: Sorry, it's an indeterminate `ProgressBar`.  I don't want to create a delay just to make it appear more pleasing, I want to avoid the display altogether unless the delay starts to exceed, say, 250ms.

Comment: Okay, gotcha.  That make more sense to me now.  What is your background operation?

Comment: I solved it another way in this case, but in the future I want to apply this to things like downloads or CPU intensive operations.  Some devices or network connections might respond quickly enough not to warrant a "please wait" popup, and other slower ones might.  Though I'm not convinced that we haven't just shifted the problem 250 ms ahead by delaying display of the progress bar.  If the operation took 251 ms, of course you'd still get the blink/glitch, but then adding a 100ms delay might make it look a bit smoother and not have as much relative performance impact.